# UITableViewController didSelectRowAt not properly dismissing

Tags: swift, uitableview, appdelegate, dismissviewcontroller

As you can see below in my code I've tried a few things to dismiss the UIViewTableController back into my parent ViewController once a row is selected to no luck

didselectRowAt code in my UITableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
    //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    print("before dismissing")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("dismissing")
        self.delegate?.showWeatherInfo()
    })
    print("after dismissing")


    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(self.searchResults[indexPath.row], completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {


            print(placemark)


        }
    })

    /*
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        self.delegate?.showWeatherInfo()
    })
     */
}
```

protocol for that same class:

```
protocol ShowWeather{
    func showWeatherInfo()
}
```

where I call it in my ViewController:

```
@IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    searchButtonUIChanges()
    textFieldBg_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //create searchresult object and add it as a subview
    searchResultController = SearchResultsController()
    searchResultController.delegate = self
    addChild(searchResultController)
    searchResultController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    searchResultController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64+textFieldBg_view.frame.size.height - 25, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 50)
    view.addSubview(searchResultController.view)
    searchResultController.didMove(toParent: self)



    let screenHeight = -(UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2 + textFieldBg_view.frame.height/2)
    textFieldBg_view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: screenHeight)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: animateDuration, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: springWithDamping, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        self.textFieldBg_view.transform = .identity
    }, completion: nil)

    searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Obviously before and after dismissing prints work but the dismissing one inside of the completion doesn't. The reason I currently don't have any info being passed back to the UIViewController yet is because, well, I haven't even gotten there yet.

And yes, in my ViewController class header I have the TableViewController class protocol, but that's irrelevant since the UITableViewController isn't even properly dismissing anyway yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dismiss the vc it's deinited so you need to pass the data before the dismiss

```
print("before dismissing \(delegate)")  // print delegate to see if nil
self.delegate?.showWeatherInfo()
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    print("dismissing")
})
```

Also if the vc is pushed inside a navigation `dismiss` won't work and you need to use

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: the dismissing print in his completion block doesn't call, so that can't be the answer.

"... the dismissing one inside of the completion doesn't."